# Interaction term in free energy for Gaussian Fixed Point

Tags: field-theory, renormalization, path-integral, regularization

In general in statistical field theory, the free energy $F_0$ as a function of our order parameter $\phi$ can be written as

$$F_0[\phi]=F_0[\phi^-]+F_0[\phi^+]+F_I[\phi^-,\phi^+]$$
where the last term is an interaction term between the short-wavelength $\phi^+$ and the high-wavelength $\phi^+$. My question is: Why is $F_I=0$ when at a Gaussian Fixed Point? I know it has to do with $F$ taking the following form, which is quadratic in $\phi$,

$$F_0[\phi]=\int^\Lambda \dfrac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}\dfrac{1}{2}(k^2+\mu^2)\phi_k\phi_{-k}$$
where $\Lambda$ is the UV cutoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your field into fast and slow modes $\phi_k = \phi_k^+ + \phi_k^-$ where the former is supported on momenta $\Lambda/b \leq |k| \leq \Lambda$ and the latter on $0\leq |k|\leq\Lambda/b$ for a choice of scale parameter $b$.

Then $$ \phi_k\phi_{-k} = (\phi_k^+ + \phi_k^-)(\phi_{-k}^+ + \phi_{-k}^-)= \phi_{k}^+\phi_{-k}^+  + \phi_{k}^-\phi_{-k}^- + 2\phi_{k}^+\phi_{-k}^-$$
where the last term is $F_I$. Due to the non-overlapping support of $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$, it is identically zero.

Note that a $\phi^4$ term yields a non-vanishing coupling between slow and fast modes due to the fact that momentum need only be conserved among four fields.

Comment: so by non-overlapping support, you mean that one of $\phi_k^+$ or $\phi_k^-$ is always going to be zero for any choice of k? Then could you elaborate more on how the conservation of momentum among four fields implies a non-vanishing coupling in $\phi^4$ terms? I haven't heard of this yet

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. You can see for yourself. Write down the analogous expression for a phi4 term. It involves three independent momentum integrals. Loosely speaking three slow momenta can make up a fast one.